# Ajax call does not work in mvc 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jquery

I am pulling my hair. For the love of my life I cannot make this work. I have a form in my view:

```
 <div id="cancel" class="cancel">
    <form method="post" class="cancelForm">
     <input type="hidden" class="cancelId" name="cancelId" value="@appliedLvl.LeavesId" />
    <input id="cancelMe" class="cancelMe" type="submit" value="Cancel"/>
  </form>
</div>
```

The javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$(".cancelForm").submit(function () {
    var MYcancelId = $('.cancelId').val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Home/Cancel",

       success: function (result) {
            alert("ok");
        },
        error: function (request, status, error) {
            debugger;
            confirm(request);
        }
    });
  })
});
```

And the Controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Cancel(Guid cancelId )
    {
        //do stuff here
        return PartialView();
    }
```

I always get into the error function of the ajax. No matter what I have tried. This same javascript code works perfectly on my php projects. Don't know what is wrong here. Thanks in advace for any help.

**Edit**

The error here was the fact that I was expecting in the Action a Guid not a string!

Comment: Are you getting an error back?  Have you tried using fiddler to see if the request is returning a different HTTP status code than you are expecting?

Answer (score 3):

You aren't passing in a cancelId parameter, so it isn't seeing your controller method.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$(".cancelForm").submit(function () {
    var MYcancelId = $('.cancelId').val();

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Home/Cancel",
    data: { cancelId = MYcancelId },
   success: function (result) {
        alert("ok");
    },
    error: function (request, status, error) {
        debugger;
        confirm(request);
    }
});
})
});
```

Comment: Yes even as such it still gives me an error. But I figured it out Thanks to Fiddler. The problem is that I'm an idiot. In the controller I am expecting a Guid whereas I am sending a string!

Comment: Ah, that would do it as well :)  I should have noticed that as well the first time around.  Fiddler is a fantastic tool, I'd always recommend starting with it.  Glad you got it figured out!

Comment: Well... The problem is that only IE seems to be working. Firefox and Chrome still get errors.

Comment: Well it seems that I get a 401.2 unauthorized request. It is an intranet application and I start to believe that it has to do with how IE handles credentials regarding Ajax requests vs the other two. Maybe I am wrong though. Any ideas?

Comment: This may help.  It looks like it might be an IIS issue if you're running through IIS http://support.microsoft.com/kb/253667.

Comment: At this point I would recommend that we consider this particular issue closed.  It sounds like your error is another question in entirety.

Comment: Yes thank you for your help. I might do a Q&A if I find the answer. But it's not going to happen at 4 am :-/

Comment: Understandable and glad to help get you this far.  Best of luck on resolving your issue.  If I was able to help I'd greatly appreciate an accepted answer :)